# Mysql search month varchar field

Tags: mysql

I have departure data table:

```
dep_date
10/01/2018
21/02/2018
14/03/2018
25/04/2018
```

Where `dep_date` field is Varchar
How do I search for month=3 in `dep_date`?

Comment: Store dates as dates, not as varchars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use  `like %/03/%`.

Or the complete line is:

```
select * from table_name where dep_date like '%/03/%';
```

Answer (score -2):

I would like to suggest you to use date type to store date in database instead of varchar.

Try Following Command : (With date type)

```
Select * FROM departure WHERE MONTH(dep_date) = 3
```

:)

Comment: `MONTH` is a date function and not for string. I tried `SELECT MONTH('14/03/2018');`and got `NULL`. `SELECT MONTH(14/03/2018);` yielded `0` instead. So I think your answer isn't good.

Comment: Wrong @kiamoz MONTH([varchar_column]) will work just fine if the format in the varchar column is a valid MySQL date format. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/095f2b/1

Comment: oop , I'm very very very very  sorry ,  please  add some edit to your answer that next I can remove my negative point , sorry  again